# New multicollider wording ("more communities") is misleading and should be changed

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

So, I noticed we have a new multicollider design:

> [image: screenshot (with no waffles)]

But then I scrolled down and I saw this:

> [image: another screenshot (still no waffles)]

Isn't "More Stack Exchange Communities" misleading? "More" means that they're different than the previous ones, but clearly they aren't.

I suggest that it simply be "All Stack Exchange Communities."

Comment: Meh. It's kinda minor anyway, and "More" is probably clearer to newbies (who are probably the target market here).

Comment: Think it's time for a [meta-tag:site-list] tag. :)

Comment: @michaelb958 Then change it to **"List all Stack Exchange communities"**